# Modern languages and array notation convention

Tags: arrays, programming-languages, implementation, specifications

Do you know any modern language where arrays are noted as column/row instead of as it is in C++/Java/C# row/column?

Comment: Is it? I though when you define a two-dimensional array, it's up to you to define what's the rows and what's the columns.

Comment: I wonder why those downvotes? Can't I as question which I do not know answer to? And for the love of God have at least some guts to admit when you downvote. Seriously...

Comment: +1 to counter downvotes - it's a valid question (based on a misunderstanding, but that's not a crime).

Comment: That was my downvote, and it was accidental.  Sorry.  I tried to revert, but I (accidentally) cast the vote > 5 minutes ago.  If you edit the question, then I can remove the downvote.

Comment: I downvoted your question because it "is unclear or not useful", the exact text on the down arrow. None of those languages notes arrays as row/column, so the question of why they do is unclear, and as the premise of the question is untrue, asking why is not very useful to others.

Comment: @Oli thanks, now I,m waiting for the other "genius"

Comment: @Dan Thanks, but your comment above should be added without me asking for it.

Comment: No, it really shouldn't, or the two actions would be linked. Voting is not a personal message to you. The comment I made since you demanded it was a restatement of the text on the downvote button, it added no real explanation as none was needed. Get over yourself.

Comment: @Dan what's unclear about this question? And how can you decide that this question is not useful? For whom, you or others? It was useful for at least one person, me. So, yes you should comment in this case if you downvoted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of those languages have the concept of a row or column in association with arrays. It is only the programmers that associate those concepts with one dimension or another of the array. You can interchange them freely, and store either "rows" or "columns" in any part of the array.

Answer (score 2):

"Row" and "column" are just a matter of interpretation.  They don't correspond to anything fundamental in the language.

(Note: there are a few exceptions; typically dedicated maths languages, such as Matlab.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about row vs. column-major ordering then there is a subtle low-level difference. It boils down to how multi-dimensional data is stored in memory.

Check out this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) for more info.

Answer (score -2):

As others have answered, interpreting indexes as rows or columns is up to the programmer (how do you interpret an array with five dimensions?), except that a few languages or language versions specify how multi-dimensional arrays are laid out in memory, and knowing that may help improve the performance of array-intensive computations by avoiding paging and increasing the hits on the CPU caches.

That said, modern optimizing compilers should be able to figure out the most efficient way to access an array so programmers don't have to mind about memory layouts.

If [dependence analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependence_analysis) (also [Dataflow Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataflow_analysis))determines that a loop can be unfolded and that the expressions in one iteration don't depend on the ones from previous iterations, then the expressions may be reordered, for example by inverting the indexation.

It is the same kind of analysis that is done to determine if a loop is automatically parallelizable. It is something more frequently done in functional languages because the immutability of values makes the analysis easier. In procedural languages,  side-effects may hide anywhere, so the optimizations take place only for loops involving simple expressions.

Comment: That last paragraph is untrue, at the very least in C or C++.  If there's a language whose compiler can predict cache-access patterns and switch the "fast" dimension, I'd be interested to hear about it!

Comment: Even the JITter in .NET languages doesn't do this. You still need to understand what the code you're writing actually means and implement it the most logical way in the first place.

Comment: The order of execution specified by a particular program is not the only one that will produce the same result. _Dependence Analysis_ is the branch of computing that studies that. Reordering of instructions is something routinely done by optimizing compilers. Reordering the statement within nested loops requires only a little more analysis.

Comment: @Thereisnothing See: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/automatic-parallelization-with-intel-compilers/

Comment: @Apalala: Out-of-order execution and dependency analysis wont't help with switching the order of nested loops for e.g. matrix operations, except in trivial cases.  The canonical example is performing a transpose.

Comment: @Oli Quite to the contrary. Most numerical computation with matrixes is of the form D = f(A,B,C,...), so the order of nested loops is irrelevant. A transpose is a bad example, as it is totally parallelizable; swapping every A[i,j] with A[j,i] can be done even in a random order.

Comment: @Apalala: Parallelization is not the issue here.  If you do a transpose operation in a random order, you'll get horrific cache performance.

Comment: The point is that if even a random ordering will produce the same result, then an optimizer can certainly reorder to increase cache hits.